# MySQL composite key to allow a single default record

Tags: mysql, sql, composite-key

I have a table like this:

```
ID  UserID  Country IsDefault
1   7       90      0
2   7       93      0
3   7       95      1
4   7       88      0 

5   8       34      0
6   8       55      1
7   8       27      0
8   8       12      0
```

The ID is the primary key.
UserID comes from users table. CountryID comes from countries table. IsDefault shows which of the countries is the default country for a user.

Is it possible to allow only one isDefault = 1 for a UserId using composite key?
I.e. the combination UserId = 7 should have only one instance with IsDefault = 1. All other instances of UserId 7 should have isDefault 0. Same goes for UserId 8 which should have only one default country.

Comment: perhaps use a trigger?

Comment: Why not just have default country as a field in the User table?

Comment: You guys are right. But I was curious if it is possible to add a constraint like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a *partial index* (*filtered index* in SQL server) however MySQL does not support them i.e. the following in another DB (this will NOT work in MySQL)

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX yourIndexNameHere
ON yourTableNameHere (UserID) 
WHERE IsDefault=1;
```

Your options are as follows

1. Create a trigger to execute prior to INSERT and UPDATE statements that can handle your unique constraint, i.e. by setting `IsDefault` to 0 for all other rows for that `UserID` (this can be optimised i.e. ignoring the currently being updated row in an `UPDATE` and only updating where `IsDefault` is actually 1) (as suggested by Fabricator)
2. Add a `DefaultCountry` column in the users table that stores this information (as suggested by wils484)
3. Use a different database than MySQL.  SQL Server, PostgreSQL, and SQLite are able to suport partial indexes